# Social applications with Corona SDK

Tags: mobile, coronasdk

Is it possible / feasible to develop social applications with Corona SDK? I am talking about applications like Path, or a more feature rich application like Facebook for iOS?

We are going to develop a mobile application but don't want to assign resources for both iOS and Android versions of the software.

Maybe I should give more information about our project.

Users will use device camera, location services and there will be lots of web service calls as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the the camera as well.  See the media.show() API Call:  http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/show.html

Your web service access will be using the network.request() API call.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Though I'm not sure about device camera but you can use location services and you can also develop a client side in corona